# Unknown characters after formatting date on ipad(ios)

Tags: ios, ipad, core-plot, nsdateformatter

I am using core-plot for drawing bar graphs. I have displayed date on x-axis. I have used following code:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yy"];

double tickLocation=0.5;
NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[valuesArray count]];
for ( HistoryIndividualValueBean * value in valuesArray)
{
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[formatter stringFromDate:value.submittedTime] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tickLocation++] decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset       = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
    newLabel.rotation     = M_PI_2;
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
    [newLabel release];
}

[formatter release];

x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
```

This is working fine on iphone. But on ipad it displays weird characters in date(which I have formatted above). Please refer to this image:

[image]

Comment: Are you running in Chinese or Japanese locale? `月` is a symbol for "month", if I recall it right.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight great thanks. I guess this is the problem. Actually the client sent this screenshot, I'l tell him. He lives in japan so I guess this is the problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see this behavior is that `MMM` format is locale-specific. In Japan, it formats the month as month's number followed by the `月` character.

If you would like a three-letter name of the months to be displayed regardless of the locale, pick US as the locale for your formatter:

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setLocale:usLocale];
```